# The Word Am I (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, english

This Riley I hope you like!

> Out there, out there, my prefix you cannot find
>   An endless  line, a stanza, is what my infix is
>   Lost one in many, and my suffix I become
>   The word am I, as you are seeing here!

Entry into Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Riding on the backs of @WAlt's and @Dorrulf's answers and incorporating comments, I got

> **inversion**.

because

> **in** is the opposite of "out there", **vers**e is the category to which poetry comprising lines and stanzas belongs, and an **ion** [can be missing](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=ion) one of its [potentially] many electrons.*

To bring it all together, "The word am I" is

> an **inversion** of conventional syntax, which would call for "I am the word".

---

> <sup>* I guess that's a little biased. It could be missing protons, from their perspective.</sup>

Comment: Nice Job! +1, You got it

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Very much a group effort. Until the other clues I was convinced "Lost one in many" would be a needle in a haystack reference and spent all my time down that [wrong] road.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my attempt:

> **Miscellany**

Out there, out there, my prefix you cannot find

> You can't find what's **mis**sing

An endless line, a stanza, is what my infix is

> I think a blank **cell** in Braille indicates a line break (and hence a stanza)

Lost one in many, and my suffix I become

> When 'many' loses one letter it becomes '**any**'

The word am I, as you are seeing here!

> *"**am I, as [...] see**ing"* seems to be spelling out **MISC**, a common abbreviation for this word.

Comment: +1 for such a good answer, but sorry you are wrong

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Aw shucks. Ta for the tip, I'll have a rethink!

Comment: @Dorrulf 's ans is much closer to the intended answer, may be you can refer to his work? Also, both your suffixes are way off, I may add a hint afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> intercompany

Out there, out there, my prefix you cannot find

> Opposite of out there: in or inter

An endless line, a stanza, is what my infix is

> Originally thought verse, but comp can be short for composition and can be musically oriented.

Lost one in many, and my suffix I become

> Going off of @Walt's idea, many - m = any

The word am I, as you are seeing here!

> While there are many definitions, they're all similar to: a number of individuals assembled or associated together; group of people.
>  Well, that's what we have here on SE.

Comment: Well done +1, Your answer is much closer than @Walt 's, keep it up!

Comment: Also, you may rethink the suffix and try to see if any of the prefix/ infix works